# Why in PowerShell does embedding a DateTime object in a string lose the DateTime locale?

Tags: powershell

The locale of my machine is UK (en-gb). When I do the following (to check expiration date of an SSL cert) the DateTime object stores the value in UK format

`$expiration = Get-Date $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()`

See here what happens firstly if you just have the value printed to the command prompt, and secondly what happens if you try to embed that DateTime object value within a string.

```
PS>$expiration 
19 December 2016 23:59:59
PS>write-host "this is the expiration: $expiration"
this is the expiration: 12/19/2016 23:59:59
```

So we see that it has switched to non UK format (should be 19/12/2016). Why is this, and is there a simple workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a string expansion problem and a bit of a pain I'm afraid. You know this one to display incorrectly:

```
"$(Get-Date 01/02/2016)"
```

These however, display as you'd expect:

```
(Get-Date 01/02/2016).ToString()
"$((Get-Date 01/02/2016).ToString())"
```

Both of these approaches work to work around the problem:

```
$expiration = Get-Date 01/02/2016
write-host "this is the expiration: $($expiration.ToString())"
write-host ("this is the expiration: {0}" -f $expiration)
```

You see similar ignorance of the time zone when casting to DateTime:

```
[DateTime]$var = "01/02/2016"
$var
```

Chris

Comment: Thanks. Of the two I prefer the String.Format type work around. But still seems daft to me that this work around is required...

Comment: I've found another workaround which is slightly more elegant and does what I want: $ReportDate = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d@%H-%M-%S" this will preserve the format when embedded in a string.

Comment: It's even worse on a system where more than one locale is installed. If the user locale is set to 'English (World)" and the system locale is "English (US)", different versions of Powershell give different results. (v5.1 and PsCore 7, both running side by side on two tabs in Windows Terminal --> 5.1 uses the system locale for ToString(), while 7 uses the user locale.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple string format option

MSDN article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

```
$expirationString = "{0:F}" -f $expiration
```

and then

```
Write-Host "this is the expiration: $expirationString"
```

If this also provides the wrong output, you could make a custom format string, like this:

```
"{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss}"
```